# Plane Geometry about ratio of areas

Tags: plane-geometry, ratio

Point $F$ lies on the **straight** line $AC$, with which a circle centered by $F$ can be made through both $B$ and $C$. $M$ is the midpoint of the arc $BC$. The straight line $CM$ intersects the straight line $AB$ at H.

How to express the ratio of the areas of the $\triangle{CBM}$ to $\triangle{CBH}$ in the following three variables.

a) $\alpha$ : the angle $BAC$.

b) $m$ : the length of the segment $AB$.

c) $t$ : the tangent of $\angle{ACB}$.

I've tried the rules of cosines but it ain't working.

[attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Yg37.png)

Comment: Please draw a figure using Geogebra or Desmos and include it into your question.

Comment: @JeanMarie I did do that. Please take a look at the attachment. (For unknown reason I can't directly insert figures into my question)

Comment: @JeanMarie Sadly it said that I'm not allowed to do that. Maybe I haven't got enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not an answer**. Just a figure for clarification

Here is another case of figure with $F$ outside line segment $[A,C]$ ; do you accept it ?

[image]

Comment: You haven't said if you accept this case of figure ; it should be the case because $F$ is on **line** $AC$ (but not on line **segment** $AC$...)

Comment: I accept this case. The question has been edited.

Comment: You have to use the fact that triangle $CMB$ is an isosceles triangle.